# More then two rows are present for a single employee based on date and have to find most recent row for that employee

Tags: sql, date

there are more then two rows of a single employee based on date(say effdate) in table and I have to select the most recent row for that employee. please suggest a sql query
For example if a table contains
scott        22/12/1980
rambo        23/12/1990
spawn        25/12/1991
scott        22/12/2000
rambo        23/12/1970
spawn        25/12/1999

i want answer like
Scott  22/12/2000
rambo  23/12/1990
Spawn  25/12/1999

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

In sql-server

```
select top 1 * from table order by emp_date desc
```

In my-sql

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
ORDER BY emp_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

in oracle

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY  emp_date)
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

After seeing the Updated question :

In sql-server

```
select * from( 
select *,rn=row_number()over(partition by name order by date1 desc) from table
)
where rn=1
```